# Audio lessons for absolute beginners

Tags: learning

Can you recommand some good audio lessons? I need to learn German and I wanna use my "free time" for example when I'm walking with my 15m old son in the park or when I do some chores at home, I can carry with me an MP3 player, and listen to german lessons.

I know the basic (A1 level), but I don't mind learning from scratch.

I have listened and liked [Rocket German 6 Day Course](http://www.rocketlanguages.com) sample ( [here](http://www.rldownload.com/mp3/german/newsletters/SampleIntro.mp3) it is ), but I can't afford it at 299$.

I would like something similar to that, free or cheaper (under $100).

P.S. also if you have any good sugestions for "dedicated" time where I have access to a computer/internet, I already use [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/languages/german/), [DW](http://www.dw-world.de/dw/0,,2469,00.html) and [about](http://german.about.com/).

Thank you (Danke schön).

Comment: Further information [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4970/audio-ausspracheworterbuch-fur-offline-usage-fur-das-ipad).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This website has a list of free resources you could access:

http://www.openculture.com/free_german_lessons

Comment: I have listened to the first part of "Deutsch – warum nicht?", they are great especially if you know a little bit of german. Than you.

Comment: Because resources are for iTunes I can't open them as podcast in Linux (Rhythmbox), to load them in Linux, just transorm the link using this online application http://itunes.so-nik.com/