# Audio Aussprachewörterbuch für "offline usage" für das iPad?

Tags: pronunciation, book, dictionary, audio

Ich brauche akustische Ausspracheangaben (audio pronunciations) fürs iPad; auch für "offline usage". Chats zum Thema [hier](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5563477#5563477) und [hier](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5641056#5641056). 
Wo finde ich solche?

*P.s. Ich versuche auch ein Englisch-Deutsch-Englisch Wörterbuch [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5809/englisch-deutsch-englisch-worterbuch-fur-offline-usage-fur-das-ipad-oder-iphon) finden, für “offline usage” für das iPad oder iPhone.*

Comment: ...Tips [hier](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-good-online-dictionaries-for-translation-between-german-and-english) über English/Deutsch, z.B. dict.cc hat ein iPad App...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich habe nicht alle ausprobiert, aber ich denke das von Langenscheidt ist das Beste. Es hat genug Audiosamples, jedoch wenige Beispielsätze. Dafür eignet sich [Dictionary for German as a foreign language PREMIUM by PONS](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/dictionary-for-german-as-foreign/id312800936?mt=8) zum Nachschlagen von Beispielen - hat aber keine Audiosamples.

**iPad**

> 1. [Duden - German spelling dictionary, 25th edition](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/duden-german-spelling-dictionary/id324566194?mt=8) (beinhaltet aber nur 9000 Hörbeispiele)
> 2. [LinguatecApps](http://www.linguatecapps.com/)
> 3. [Langenscheidt Professional-Wörterbuch Englisch für Handys und Smartphones](http://www.langenscheidt.de/produkt/5477_8937/Langenscheidt_Professional-Woerterbuch_Englisch_fuer_Handys_und_Smartphones-App_fuer_iPhone/978-3-468-94476-5) und
>
>    [German Learner's Dictionary Langenscheidt](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/german-learners-dictionary/id378272803?mt=8)

Allgemein mehr [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4972/887), nicht nur über das iPad.

**Beachte:** *Duden, Langenscheidt und PONS haben leider eine ähnliche Benutzerschnittstelle. Ich denke es ist eine gute Idee, zwei verschiedene Bücher zu vergleichen: ein Audiobuch und ein Sammlung von Beispielsätzen, um den Redefluss zu verbessern.*

**Siehe auch folgende Fragen:**

> 1. [What are good German language programs for iPad/iPhone?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2067/what-are-good-german-language-programs-for-ipad-iphone)
> 2. [German dictionary with detailed declensions, audio pronunciations, and IPA](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3237/german-dictionary-with-detailed-declensions-audio-pronunciations-and-ipa)
> 3. [Audio lessons for absolute beginners](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2713/audio-lessons-for-absolute-beginners)

Comment: ...fragte Duden, sie wissen nicht Unterschieden zwitchen ihre Apple -Wörterbücher aber gab mir diese Seite [hier](http://www.duden.de/iphone-apps).

Comment: I tried to amend your text. Please have a look at my changes if everything still is as what you meant to say. Furthermore, I had some trouble improving you last paragraph, since I'm not sure what you meant by "They have a similar interface, not good".

Comment: Um, to some extent. What is important to me as user are: 1. look&feel, 2. features (samples, examples, etc.), 3. quantity of data, 4. quality of data. But in the end of course they do have a similar interface, I would be surprised if not. That's the reason I didn't understand what you meant to say. I always try several dictionaries and stay with the best and/or use a couple of dictionaries for different purposes, i.e. reverse lookup, context search, synonyms, ... However, I'm still not sure how to improve your sentence, I'll skip it ;)

Comment: Well, however, I'm not sure if it's really the UI what does matter. Having had a quick look at the app store I'd state down something along: "Note: D, L and P do support similar features and their chief distinction is the quantity in data they incorporated, but all of them include the most important words and phrases. Thus I'd suggest to choose two different kind of apps, an audio tool focusing on pronunciation and a collection of phrases and proverbs". But don't wanna be dogmatically, just telling my thoughts...